# How to print a word document from Python in A5 size?

Tags: python, printing, python-docx

I'm making a program which prints out receipts on word documents. 
I need the print-outs on A5 size sheets.

This seems to work, but I don't know how to configure it to A5 size.

```
from win32com import client
import time

word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

def printWordDocument(filename):

    word.Documents.Open(filename)
    word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut()
    time.sleep(2)
    word.ActiveDocument.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

I manually set the dimensions in python-docx, which was a bit tedious, but I couldn't find a better alternative.